# Get the 3rd element (table) on webpage using Selenium find element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, html-table, selenium-chromedriver

```
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table")
```

This is working but finds the first table on webpage, there are three on the page and I want the third, how can I find the third table element, or otherwise uniquely identify and find the correct table?

```
<table class="sortable" id="results" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" align="center" border="0">
    <caption>...</caption>
    <thread>...</thread>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br>
 <div>
<table class="sortable" id="results" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" align="center" border="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(//table)[1]` - This will locate the first table in the DOM, `(//table)[2]`this will locate the second table in the DOM and so on.

Try the below to locate third table:

```
third_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//table)[3]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the id:

```
third_table = driver.find_element(By.ID, "results")
```

You can also use full XPath but there's no guarantee it will stay the same if the DOM changes.